# Getting linking error 2019 although class is not derived from CString class in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, lnk2019

i am getting the following error

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class
>   ATL::CStringT > > __thiscall
>   CFILicenseSettings::GetCodeStartup1(void)"
>   (?GetCodeStartup1@CFILicenseSettings@@QAE?AV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ)
>   referenced in function
>   __catch$?ValidateLicense@CFIServerDlg@@AAE_NXZ$0  E:\TIMSWebServerManager_lic\TIMSWebServerManager\TIMSWebServerManager.obj   TIMSWebServerManager

My function defination is as follows:

```
CString CFILicenseSettings::GetCodeStartup1()
{
CString a = "why";
return a;
}
```

the declaration of the function is as follows:-

```
CString     GetCodeStartup1();
```

When i searched the web for the above error i found that this error is because my class is derived from  CString class,but this is not the case.....
I get this error when i call the function GetCodeStartup1();
if i comment the calling of function GetCodeStartup1(); my program compile successfully

How can i remove the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This error is not because the compiler thinks your class is derived from `CString`.  Are you sure the file that contains the definition of `CFILicenseSettings::GetCodeStartup1()` is actually being compiled (maybe introduce an intentional syntax error to verify you're editing the file that's being compiled)?  Did you try performing a clean then a rebuild?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ya sir i try'ed everything possible

Comment: What output do you get if you run `dumpbin /symbols filename.obj | find "GetCodeStartup1"` on the object file that `CString CFILicenseSettings::GetCodeStartup1()` is supposed to be in? (please edit the output into the question, as it'll likely be too ugly for a comment).